# Why Jest doesn't recognise Server instance with Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, integration-testing

First, I'm a bit of a beginner. I created an Express project using express-generator which contains a file: bin/www. www is actually a javascript file containing the server creation like below code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// This file is generated by express generator

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('happy-meal:server');
var http = require('http');


var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {}
function onError(error) {}
function onListening() {}

// Added by myself
exports.module = server;
```

The last line I added myself to get access to Server instance in jest test.

So, I want to run a simple integration test with the following code:

```
// integration test: users.test.js
const request = require("supertest");

describe("/api/v1/users", () => {

    let server;

    beforeEach(() => {
        server = require("../../bin/www");
    });
    afterEach(() => {
        server.close();
    });

    describe("GET /", () => {
        it("should return all users", async (done) => {
            const res = await request(server).get("/api/v1/users");

            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

This resulted in the following error output of jest:

```
TypeError: app.address is not a function

      14 |     describe("GET /", () => {
      15 |         it("should return all users", async (done) => {
    > 16 |             const res = await request(server).get("/api/v1/users");
         |                                               ^
      17 | 
      18 |             expect(res.status).toBe(200);
      19 |             done();

      at Test.serverAddress (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:55:18)
      at new Test (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:36:12)
      at Object.get (node_modules/supertest/index.js:25:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/integration/users.test.js:16:47)

  ● /api/v1/users › GET / › should return all users

    TypeError: server.close is not a function

       9 |     });
      10 |     afterEach(() => {
    > 11 |         server.close();
         |                ^
      12 |     });
      13 | 
      14 |     describe("GET /", () => {

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/integration/users.test.js:11:16)
```

It looks like it doesn't recognise the "server"-variable as a Server object. Because of that, "server.close()" doesn't work, as a result the server is not shut down. Also the get-request doesn't work. Once again, the server object is not seen as a Server instance.

What am I doing wrong? I hope you can help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request(server)` won't work, you have to use your `app` instance instead:

```
const app = require('../../app'); // Where your app instance is

...

const res = await request(app).get("/api/v1/users");
```

Also, try to import your server above all to see if it is recognized as Server object.

**Edit**

Either you want to create http server every test, either you want to do create http server once for all tests and then close it after tests end. Try this :

```
// integration test: users.test.js
const http = require('http');
const request = require("supertest")
const app = require('../../app'); // Where your app instance is

describe("/api/v1/users", () => {
  beforeAll(done => {
      server = http.createServer(app);
      server.listen(done);
  });

  afterAll(done => {
      server.close(done);
  });

  describe("GET /", () => {
        it("should return all users", async (done) => {
            const res = await request(app).get("/api/v1/users");

            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited my answer, try with this new solution, it worked for me. If not, log us the error and what is in app file

Comment: Thnx my friend, this worked! Please add "const http = require('http');" at the top (for other developers). You really helped me out with this one.

Comment: You are welcome mate ! Oh yeah sorry I forgot !! Thanks :)